# How to toggle the z-index values to make the image appear into front or to background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have many images which are overlapped on top of each other, I am trying to make the selected image to appear front or into background on click functionality. Toggling of images is working fine except for the top most image(image1 ) when the page loads.

When the page is first loaded and if I click the top most image, it should hide behind the 2nd image. But this is not happening because z-index of all images are set to 0 initially.

> Expectation : The top most image should hide when I click it and the toggle should work for all images.

`jQuery` code to toggle the z-index values for the images:

```
function selectelement(){
  $("img.imgClass").click(function() {
    if($(this).css("z-index")=="0"){
      $(this).css("z-index",100); 
    }else{
      $(this).css("z-index",0); 
    } 
    return this;
  });
}
```

HTML code for Image :

```
<div class="imgContainer">
<span ng-repeat="addOn in viewModel.actSlideShow.children[viewModel.currentSlide].children >
<img class="imgClass ng-scope" ng-click="selectelement()" ng-src="pictures/vivek/bg1.jpg" alt="pictures/vivek/bg1.jpg" src="pictures/vivek/bg1.jpg"></span></div>
```

CSS for Images:

```
img {
    max-width: 455px;
    max-height: 303px;
    transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px;
    border-style: hidden;
    border-width: thin;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: You are using ng-click to bind eventHandler, but that eventHandler just adds another eventHandler...

Comment: you have a missing " before the span closing bracket

Comment: yes, i will correct it but do u have any idea how to make the topmost image to toggle ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Created a working version to illustrate.

https://jsfiddle.net/kvs32wtd/1/

```js
$("img.imgClass").click(function() {

  $('img.imgClass').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('id'))
    a = parseInt($(this).css("z-index"));
    $(this).css("z-index", a + 1)
  });

  a = $(this).css("z-index") - 1;

  $(this).css("z-index", a);
  return this;
});
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 455px;
  max-height: 303px;
  transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px;
  border-style: hidden;
  border-width: thin;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="imgContainer">
  <img class="imgClass" id="one" src="https://photogallerylinks.com/pics/1651.jpg">
  <img class="imgClass" id="two" src="https://www.timeshighereducation.com/sites/default/files/small_building.jpg">
  <img id="three" class="imgClass" src="https://photogallerylinks.com/pics/1648.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add "Position: relative" to the CSS of the element you wish to apply a different z-index to.

You can do this in code:

```
$(this).css("position", "relative");
```

Or just directly in CSS:

```
img {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 455px;
  max-height: 303px;
  transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px;
  border-style: hidden;
  border-width: thin;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

Else, z-index will not have any impact.

Comment: Thanks @Happysmithers , I have added the position property but even after adding it , the topmost image is not hiding behind other images.z-index for other images are working fine .

Comment: please post a version that can be reproduced directly

Comment: Please find the working codepen https://codepen.io/vivekhegde99/pen/QqLNox

Comment: Here the topmost image is hiding behind the other images on click , But the other images are toggling properly.could you please help me out here .

Comment: you will need to adjust the z-index of all images in question, else several images will end up with a z-index of 100 and thus no clear preference given...

Comment: See this example: clicking the topmost image will keep hiding it and others pop up... i am counting down the z-index by one on each click, starting at 1000... so the solution needs to reshuffle all images on each click. https://jsfiddle.net/kvs32wtd/

Comment: Would it also be possible to make the background image appear front when i click the background image like toggle .https://jsfiddle.net/kvs32wtd/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154141/discussion-between-happysmithers-and-vivek).

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("img.imgClass").click(function() {

  $('img.imgClass').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('id'))
    a = parseInt($(this).css("z-index"));
    $(this).css("z-index", a + 1)
  });

  a = $(this).css("z-index") - 1;

  $(this).css("z-index", a);
  return this;
});
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 455px;
  max-height: 303px;
  transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px;
  border-style: hidden;
  border-width: thin;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="imgContainer">
  <img class="imgClass" id="one" src="https://photogallerylinks.com/pics/1651.jpg">
  <img class="imgClass" id="two" src="https://www.timeshighereducation.com/sites/default/files/small_building.jpg">
  <img id="three" class="imgClass" src="https://photogallerylinks.com/pics/1648.jpg">
</div>
```